# Is it possible to override UpdateAction in jquery jtable?

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-jtable

I am populating some data in a table using `jquery jtable`. I would like to override the `updateAction` in it. I would like to add few more fields in the `updateAction popup`. Is it even possible? If yes, how can i achieve it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#TableContainer').jtable({
            title : 'User List',
            actions : {
                listAction : 'Controller?action=list',
                updateAction: 'Controller?action=update',
                deleteAction: 'Controller?action=delete' 
            },
            fields : {
                num : {
                    title : 'No',
                    width : '30%',
                    key : true,
                    list : true,
                    create : true
                },
                psid : {
                    title : 'Id',
                    width : '30%',
                    edit : false
                },
                roles : {
                    title : 'Roles',
                    width : '30%',
                    edit : true

                    // options: 'Controller?action=list' 
                   /* options:["jj","kk"] */

                },
                country : {
                    title : 'Country',
                    width : '20%',
                    edit : true
                },
                /* CustomAction: {
                    title: '',
                    width: '1%',
                    sorting: false,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: true,
                    display: function (data) {
                        if (data.record) {
                            return '<button title="Edit Record" class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button" onclick="alert(' + data.record.TicketId + '); return false;"><span>Edit Record</span></button>';
                        }
                    }
                },
                 */
                recordsLoaded: function(event, data) {
                    $('.jtable-data-row').click(function() {
                        var row_id = $(this).attr('data-record-key');
                        alert('clicked row with id '+row_id);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        $('#TableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
</script>
```

And i would like to add values dynamically from json in dropdown. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with option `edit:true` for that field? If you just want to display the few fields only on editing the form. But you've add those field in your table.

For example,

```
TicketId : {
    title: 'Ticket ID',
    width: '15%',
    list : false,
    create: false,        //Make it false when create
    edit: true
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. And can you recommend something to add values dynamically in the drop down instead of doing something like "options: ['2', '3']"

Comment: I don't get you, If you add values how will you get back the selected options?

Comment: I need to send the selected options to the server. So, is it not possible to add values dynamically in drop down box?

Comment: I mean this will be more comfortable for you to iterate in jsp as `String[]`. If you never mind, why do you want to add dropddown values?